# Retrieving data from a Rails 4.2.5.1 app using Unity 5.3.5

Tags: c#, php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine

First time asking a question here so just let me know if I have forgotten anything important!

I currently have a system in which a user's highscores for a game being developed in Unity 5.3.5 are stored in a MySQL database. As a part of this system, I am also developing a web app using Ruby on Rails 4.2.5.1, which is what I am using to get the data from the game to the MySQL database, and which I also plan to use to visualize data (and other features not related to this question).

My current issue is that I am trying to display that data from the database back in Unity, but I have been having trouble accessing the information I need. I have been trying to use Unity's WWW class through `WWW.text`, but that just ends up giving me all the HTML code in addition to the information I need (we're talking about A LOT of HTML code here).

I have done this successfully in PHP before. For example, I wrote my own version of this script from a Unity tutorial on server-side highscores (the following is just an example I used as a reference, it's pretty old code from what I understand): http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores#PHP_-_display.php

When using this script (ex. www.example.com/display.php), I was able to get the information I needed (something along the lines of `Jon 10` for example). In  my rails app right now I have tried to do the same, but have not been able to access that data.

In one of my controllers I have the following code which retrieves the data I want from my database:

```
def getData
  @current_highscores = MyModelName.order(score: :desc).pluck(:username, :score)
end
```

In one of my views I also have the following code that displays the scores on the web page (ex. www.example.com/data/getData):

```
<% @current_highscores.each do |highscore| %>
  <%= highscore %>
<% end %>
```

This displays the information I pulled from the database in the format that I want (ex. `Jon 10'), but like I mentioned earlier I am not sure how to get that data from the database back into my game. I am a bit new to Ruby on Rails and am struggling to figure out a proper solution to this, so any help or advice that anyone has would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to return a json containing the information you need. Then parse it in your Unity3D app.

Comment: Hmm, while I am familiar with json, I'm not sure how I would be able to acquire that information (similar to my situation now). I'm guessing I would need to download the json file to my Unity3D app? Or is there some other way of reading the json file on the Rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familar with ruby on rails but you should be able to return a json containing the information you need.

See [how to return json in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324298/how-to-return-json-in-ruby) and [rails3 how to return a json document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965060/rails-3-how-to-return-a-json-document) on how to return json from rails.

Then parse it in your Unity3D app. [Many json parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965060/rails-3-how-to-return-a-json-document) are available. I used [LitJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239167/using-litjson-in-unity3d) in a project and I think it is quite easy to work with.

Use [UnityEngine.WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) to get the json you need.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! Those links you provided got me going in the right direction and I was able to get the data as a json to my game.

Comment: As for the Json parser, Unity comes equipped with the JsonUtility. Not necessarily the best and most flexible but it does the basics.